# How many intersects are in the table?

Tags: postgresql

```
longitude | latitude
----------+---------
1         | 2
2         | 3
4         | 5
2         | 3
5         | 6
1         | 2
```

How can I find how many intersects points are on the table? In this case 1,2 e 2,3

SELECT ST_Intersects

Comment: `select longitude, latitude
from x 
group by longitude, latitude
having count(*) > 1`

Answer (score 2):

E.g:

```
select longitude, latidude, count(0) intersects from
 table_name group by  longitude, latidude having count(0) > 1
```

Comment: There is no benefit whatsoever using `count(0)` instead of `count(*)`

Comment: Yes, I have grown my own habit